# Getting a word from numbers with combinations

Tags: python, combinations, probability

i'll make an example: i have the word lol that can be 1o1. the number "1" can be used as l, i, j. i have a blacklisted word list `blacklisted = ['lol']`. I want to change the "1" numbers in 1o1 to verify if it is egual to lol. Example: `result = ['ioi', 'joj', 'lol', 'joi']`...

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to understand properly. Can you please explain in bit more details with examples and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blacklisted = ['lol']
check = ['1o1']
substitute = ['l', 'i', 'j']

result = [ check[0].replace('1', char) for char in substitute ]

print(result)
```

Obiously, you can generalize the snippet above for other values than '1' and use it in a loop that checks many words.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to store these similar values. For example, here's a function to implement this functionality:

```
def check(string, blacklisted):
    translate_dict = {'1': ['l', 'i', 'j']} # etc. for similar corresponding values
    possible_strings = []
    for num, letter in translate_dict.items(): # this loop replaces all numbers with letters
        for i in letter:
            possible_strings.append(string.replace(num, i)) 
    for string in possible_strings:
        if string in blacklisted: # checks whether the string is in blacklisted
            return False
    return True
```